# Ionic keyboard pushing content issue

Tags: cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, keyboard

I'm working on an ionic app, my first page contains an input
I don't haveproblems with scrolling, but when the keyboard is opened it covers all half of my page and i need to scroll down to find my input..
how can i make the keybord pushes the content strating from the input on focus mode?

Comment: check if you have this line somewhere in your run function: `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);`

Comment: i do have it, that allows the scrolling option.. i need my keyboard to push the content in order to be in the position just under my input..

Comment: `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);` will disable scrolling my friend, remove it and the page will scroll to the input and show it above the keyboard

Comment: what version of ionic are you using ?